# failed to display array items and flags error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm a newbee still flirting around reactjs. why do i get this error anytime i trying displaying the array content of tasks.
this is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react'
import './index.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';
// import Message from './components/Message';
// import FunctionClick from './components/FunctionClick';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'This is the first text',
      day: 'Feb 5th at 2:30pm',
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Meeting at School',
      day: 'Feb 6th at 1:30pm',
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'third meeting',
      day: 'Feb 6th at 1:30pm',
      reminder: true,
    },
  ])
 
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>
    </div>
  
  );

}

export default App;
```

and this is my Tasks.js

```
import React from 'react'
import  Task  from './Task'

const Tasks = ({tasks}) => {
  
  return (
    <>
    {tasks.map((task) => (
    <Task key={task.id} task={task} />
    ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Tasks
```

Task.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Task = ({task}) => {
  return (
    <div className='task'>
        <h3>{task.text}
        </h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Task;
```

it doesn't show error in the console but shows in the browser. i've been stuck. help me please. you can try testing it on your app. thanks

Comment: which error can you see in the browser?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). i don't know if it has anything to do with the version of reactjs i use

Comment: Please provide code for `Task.js`

Comment: it has been provided in the post, (updated)

Comment: Seems the issue isn't related to these code snippets because I can't reproduce it. Recreated your code snippets here: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-booth-e6xwr5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ok. when you put on the codes in App.js file and run it , it works. but try separating the code to different files, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per your error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

if you make changes as following

```
const Tasks = ({tasks}) => {
  if(tasks && tasks.length > 0) {
    return (
      <>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={task.id} task={task} />
       ))}
       </>
     )
    }
   else return null;
}
```

then you can skip that error, As you can see I put if condition inside `Tasks` component to check `tasks` array

Comment: that has worked, thanks. but i'll need you to explain to me what caused the error and how that fixed it cos i'm a newbee, appreciate

Comment: while rendering your component might be it is not getting `tasks` array initially so that it is throwing error

Comment: ok got that. but why is the error message isn't relating to that, makes it hard to debug.